# Vue 2 Composition API Vee-Validate reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, vee-validate

I am building a simple page with Vue 2, @vue/composition-api:1.7.1, and vee-validate:3.4.14. I am running into an interesting problem. My firstname variable is reactive outside of my ValidationObserver but inside my ValidationObserver it never updates as I type. I will also get an error that no such validator exists as required but it does exist. Any reason why I would get these two behaviors?

```
    <template>
  <div>
    {{ firstname }}
    <ValidationObserver tag="testtest" v-slot="{ invalid }">
      <h2>Test test</h2>
      {{ firstname }}
      <ValidationProvider
        rules="required"
        name="first name"
        v-slot="{ errors }"
        data-testid="name-input"
        class="acds-row"
      >
        <input v-model="firstname" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
        <div v-if="errors[0]" class="error" data-testid="validation-error-integration-firstName">
          {{ errors[0] }}
        </div>
      </ValidationProvider> 
    </ValidationObserver>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, reactive } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TestCom',
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    ValidationProvider,
  },

  setup() {
    console.log('---1---');
    const title1 = ref('test component');
    const firstname = ref('first name');

    return {
      title1,
      firstname,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```